# How to edit a package listing

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I edit my package on the list at:
http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php

I would like to change its name, website, and description.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11452/how-to-edit-a-package-listing./) by [DavidKotfis](https://answers.ros.org/users/1186/davidkotfis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-10-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The online documentation on the browse list is based on the output of our indexer.  If you change the data in your source it should be recrawled in approximately 24 hours.  If that doesn't work please provide more info on what your package is and we can look into it more specifically.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3